# Change in temperature of dielectric when capacitor is charged and discharged

Tags: energy, capacitance, dielectric

Suppose I have a capacitor with a dielectric between its plates. Intially the temperature of dielectric is $T_{-1}$. The capacitor is fully charged and the temperature of dielectric is noted.. say, $T_{0}$ . The capacitor is then discharged through a resistor. The temperature of the dielectric is noted again , say $T_{1}$ . Assuming that the capacitor completely discharges and that the dielectric is an ideal linear isotropic and that the system is isolated. Would all these temperatures be equal? Will one be greater than the other? Identify the order.

I think that **$T_{1}>T_{0}=T_{-1}$** or maybe **$T_{1}>T_{0}>T_{-1}$**

given that the dielectric constant is $K$
 And that the capacitor carries $0$ charge initially(at the beginning of experiment) , it has plate area $A$ and distance between plates $d$ and is ideal. What is the right answer?
Please also tell why you think your answer is correct?